# Table only works once

Tags: mediawiki

I'm having trouble with tables in Mediaw!iki. When creating a specific table for a home page it works correctly once and is broken the second time. A screenshot is shown below

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

The code is displayed at the bottom. Does anyone know why the visual box only displays correctly once?

Thank you in advance!

```
<!--        Lorem ipsum        -->
{| id="mp-lower" style="margin:4px 0 0 0; width:100%; background:none; border-spacing: 0px;"
| class="MainPageBG" style="width:100%; border:1px solid #ddcef2; background:#faf5ff; vertical-align:top; color:#000;" |
{| id="mp-bottom" style="vertical-align:top; background:#faf5ff; color:#000; width:33%"
| style="padding:2px;" | <h2 id="mp-tfp-h2" style="margin:3px; background:#ddcef2; font-size:120%; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #afa3bf; text-align:center; color:#000; padding:0.2em 0.4em"> [[Lorem ipsum]] 
|-
| style="color:#000; padding:2px;" | <div id="mp-tfp">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
|}
|}

<!--        Lorem ipsum        -->
{| id="mp-lower" style="margin:4px 0 0 0; width:100%; background:none; border-spacing: 0px;"
| class="MainPageBG" style="width:100%; border:1px solid #ddcef2; background:#faf5ff; vertical-align:top; color:#000;" |
{| id="mp-bottom" style="vertical-align:top; background:#faf5ff; color:#000; width:33%"
| style="padding:2px;" | <h2 id="mp-tfp-h2" style="margin:3px; background:#ddcef2; font-size:120%; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #afa3bf; text-align:center; color:#000; padding:0.2em 0.4em"> [[Lorem ipsum]] 
|-
| style="color:#000; padding:2px;" | <div id="mp-tfp">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
|}
|}
```

Comment: Your code works fine [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Sandbox).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not sure why it's not working on my own wiki.

Comment: Have you tried closing the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fizzisist showed me that the problem isn't Mediawiki but something pertaining to my particular installation.

Thanks

Comment: This answer should be a comment, or you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14551826/edit) your question